# ROC vs stability in z domain?

Tags: poles-zeros, stability

I have read in some dsp texts that when ROC includes unit circle,system is stable

But i am bit confused in difference between stability and marginal stability depending Upon ROC

Especially i am confused by part c of below dsp.se question

[Z transform stability](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/z-transform-stability)

Where in part **C, ROC is 1/3 < |z| < 1** and analysis answer of part c is written as "non-causal & marginally stable" . I am confused by marginal stability. why it is marginally stable?If our **ROC is changed to 1/3 < |z| < 1.1**, will now it becomes stable or will it still remains marginally stable?

Comment: By **which** part are you confused? Can you try to more precisely point out what you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marginally stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability) means that an otherwise stable system has one or more simple poles on the unit circle (in discrete time), or on the imaginary axis (in continuous time).

The consequence of that is that transients don't decay, but they also don't grow without bounds. Marginally stable systems are unstable in the [bounded-input bounded-output (BIBO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability) sense.

Comment: By simple poles, you mean non repeated poles?

Comment: @Man: No, single distinct poles, not multiple poles.

Comment: If we had  ROC as 1/3 < |z| < 1.1, will it become fully stable?

Comment: @Man: Yes, in that case it can't be marginally stable (I would have hoped that that had become clear in my answer).

Comment: will it not be stable in this new case?because now roc includes unit circle?but you are saying it will be marginally stable

Comment: @Man: No, I said it *cannot* be marginally stable. It's indeed stable if the ROC includes the unit circle.

Comment: please kindly update your answer to include idea of your last comment

Comment: @Man: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I have understood.  Thanks